# Proving $\mathbb{Q}$ not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{+}$

Tags: group-theory

> Question: Prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ under addition is not isomorphic to  $\mathbb{R^{+}}$ under multiplication.

I wonder what is a good way to approach this? Would constructing a map be more helpful?

Thank in advance. Hints only*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: To have isomorphism, you need a bijection. Why can't a bijection exist?

Comment: Simply because 0 is not in the positive reals. I can take it from here.

Comment: Just think about the sets (don't worry about the group structure). Further hint: What is the cardinality of $\mathbb Q$? What is the cardinality of $\mathbb R^+$?

Comment: My knowledge of sets is pretty rusty. But I think this is related to countably finite and countably infinite.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: An isomorphism must in particular be a bijection.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\;\mathbb{Q}\,$ is countable, $\,\mathbb{R}^+\,$ is not.

Comment: I have to admit this is good.

Comment: @Mathematicing That's essentially what the other answers were hinting at as well.

Comment: I got it. 
0/1 maps to 0 in the natural, 1/1 maps to 1 in the natural, 2/1 maps to 2 in the naturals, and so on. There exists a one-to-one correspondence with the natural. This cannot be said to be the same for the positive reals.

Comment: @Mathematicing I don't think you've actually described a bijection to the naturals: what does 3/4 go to? But you should be able to find a proof that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countably infinite very easily in your favorite resource on introductory set theory.

Answer (score 1):

The group $\mathbb{R}^+$ with respect to multiplication is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to addition, via logarithm and exponential.

The group $\mathbb{Q}$ has the property that for all $x$ and $y$ there exist integers $m$ and $n$, not both zero, such that
$$
mx+ny=0
$$

Does $\mathbb{R}$ share this property?

Comment: You're not wrong, but this is too involved. A cardinality argument is much easier.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk A different point of view. The isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^+$ with multiplication and $\mathbb{R}$ with addition is basic knowledge. Pointing to an *algebraic* property that holds in one group and not in the other one is the prime method for showing they're not isomorphic.